Determine the convexity of a ball in a metric space.
Let $V$ be the set of all Lebesgue  integrable functions. $V$ forms a vector space with respect to general function addition and scalar multiplication. Let $X \subset V$ is the set of positive and Lebesgue  integrable functions  defined on $[0,1]$ such that
$$\forall f \in X, 0< f< +\infty, \int_{0}^{1}f(x)\mathrm{d}x=1. $$
We know $X$ is convex, since $\forall f,g \in X,\lambda \in [0,1], \int_{0}^{1} \lambda f(x) +(1-\lambda) g(x) \mathrm{d}x=1.$
$\forall f,g \in X$, $d(f,g)$ is defined as:
$$ d(f,g):= \int_{0}^{1}\bigg|\log\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \bigg| \mathrm{d}x.  $$
It can be verified that $d$ satisfies: non-negativity, symmetry, and triangle inequality.
Define ball at $f_0 \in X$ as
$$B(f_0,r)=\{ f\in X:d(f,f_0)\leq r \}.$$
I cannot determine whether the ball $B(f_0,r)$ is convex.  This question can be reduced to checking whether the following inequality holds:
$$ d(\lambda f + (1-\lambda)g,f_0) \leq r,\quad \forall f,g \in B(f_0,r),\lambda \in [0,1]. \quad (1)  $$
Or prove its stronger form:
$$ d(\lambda f + (1-\lambda)g,f_0) \leq \lambda d(f,f_0)+(1-\lambda)d(g,f_0),\quad \forall f,g \in B(f_0,r),\lambda \in [0,1]. \quad (2) $$
Could anyone provide me some hints?
Update: The stronger inequation Eq (2) is not true. This is a counterexample:
$$ f(x)=\frac{1}{1-\cos(1)+0.01}(\sin(x)+0.01), g(x)=\frac{1}{\sin(1)}\cos(x).$$
$$f_0(x)=\frac{1}{\log(1/\cos(1))+0.01}(\tan(x)+0.01)$$
It can be verified that $f,g,f_0 \in X$.
Let $\lambda=1/2$, $d(\frac{f}{2} + \frac{g}{2},f_0)\approx 0.6014, \frac{d(f,f_0)}{2}\approx 0.0911, \frac{d(g,f_0)}{2} \approx 0.4528.$ We have
$$d(\frac{f}{2} + \frac{g}{2},f_0)> \frac{d(f,f_0)}{2}+ \frac{d(g,f_0)}{2} . $$

If we let $Y \subset V$ denote the set of $\log f$ with $f \in X$, then $d$ is induced by the $L^1$-norm on $Y$. This looks useful....

@AndrewD.Hwang I don't know how to use this fact.

I was playing around with this, and I am not sure if your distance function $d$ is well-defined on all of $X$. Let $f(x) = 4x-1$ and $g(x)=1$. Note that $\int_0^1(4x-1)dx=\frac{4}{2}(1)^2 - \frac{4}{2}(1)^2 - 1(1) + 1(0) = 2-1 = 1$ and $\int_0^1 1 dx = 1$ so $f,g \in X$. But
$$\int_0^1\left| \log\left(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right)dx \right|
= \int_0^1\bigg| \log\left(4x-1\right) \bigg| = +\infty$$

Some authors allow distance functions to take infinite values.

I will check this. However, the example you provide is not appropriate, as $X$ is the set of positive functions.

Ah I missed that

@NaturalLogZ I have modified my question
